# Why React Router NavLink prop exact (v5) vs. end (v6) lead to different result with trailing slash in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In React Router Version 5 I had a `NavLink` which looked the following:

```
<NavLink
  to="/notes"
  exact={true}
  className="border-transparent text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800 block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 text-base font-medium"
  activeClassName="bg-indigo-50 border-indigo-500 text-indigo-700 block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 text-base font-medium"
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

It recognized both `localhost:3000/notes` and `localhost:3000/notes/` with a trailing slash as active urls.

In React Router Version 6 I refactored it to the following:

```
<NavLink
  to="/notes" end
  className={(navData) =>
  navData.isActive
    ? "bg-indigo-50 border-indigo-500 text-indigo-700 block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 text-base font-medium"
    : "border-transparent text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800 block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 text-base font-medium"
  }
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

This recognizes only `localhost:3000/notes` as active url.

Is there a way in v6 to have also the version with trailing slash recognized as an active url?

Comment: Because `react-router-dom` is freakin' mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've mixed up what the `react-router-dom` v5 `exact` prop represents, or rather, that you've conflated the behavior between the [`exact`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool) and [`strict`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/strict-bool) props.

## v5

- `exact`: When `true`, the active class/style will only be applied if the location is ***matched exactly***.
- `strict`: When `true`, the trailing slash on a location’s pathname will be taken into consideration when determining if the location matches the current URL. See the [`<Route strict>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/strict-bool) documentation for more information.

Note the emphasis regarding exactly matching is mine.

## v6

In `react-router-dom` version 6 all routes/links are always exactly matched. The `end` prop of the `NavLink` has more to do with the trailing slash `"/"` than it does route matching.

> If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched
> as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to
> render a link that is only active at the website root and not any
> other URLs, you can use:
>
> ```
> <NavLink to="/" end>
>   Home
> </NavLink>
> ```

To address your question

> Why React Router NavLink prop exact (v5) vs. end (v6) lead to
> different result with trailing slash in url

This is because you are comparing apples to oranges. If you want to achieve the same link behavior from v5 to v6 regarding the trailing slash `"/"` then omit the `end` prop.

```
<NavLink
  to="/notes"
  className={(navData) =>
    navData.isActive
      ? "bg-indigo-50 border-indigo-500 text-indigo-700 block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 text-base font-medium"
      : "border-transparent text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800 block pl-3 pr-4 py-2 border-l-4 text-base font-medium"
  }
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```

[image: Edit why-react-router-navlink-prop-exact-v5-vs-end-v6-lead-to-different-result-w]

Comment: thanks for your answer! however, the issue is that the initial reason why I added `end` is that I have another route `notes/create`. When omitting `end` and navigating to `notes/create` unfortunately "notes w/o end prop"-version is also shown as active, see also here: https://codesandbox.io/s/why-react-router-navlink-prop-exact-v5-vs-end-v6-lead-to-different-result-w-forked-5xyot

Comment: @Daniel So then use the `end` prop for the `"/notes"` route so it's only "active" when `"/notes"` is the leaf node, i.e. when the path is exactly `"/notes"`, like the "/notes w/ end prop" link.

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that when navigating to `/notes/` with a trailing slash it won't be recognized as active,...so basically, I have to choose between (1) adding `end` to `/notes` which solves the issue with it being shown as active when I am on `/notes/create` but causing the problem that it is not shown as active when I am on `/notes/` or (2) omitting `end` for  `/notes` which solves the issue with it not being shown as active when on `/notes/` but causing the problem that it will be shown as active when on `/notes/create`´...with v5 you could solve this with `exact={true}`

Comment: @Daniel Why are you even navigating to a path with a trailing slash like `"/notes/"`? Seems it should either be the `"/notes"` segment, or a sub-route like `"/notes/create"`. Are you trying to place something between these two?

Comment: I thought that a user might do that, so I wanted to have the UI working correctly for this case

Comment: @Daniel I see. That seems a bit silly. I'm not sure there's a way to cover both cases at the same time other than specifying both links and matching routes, or just using opinionated routes and links sans trailing slashes and redirect any unknown routes back to known, handled nested routes.

Comment: @Daniel Ack, hmm, seems in a basic configuration `"/notes"` and `"/notes/"` match the same. https://codesandbox.io/s/why-react-router-navlink-prop-exact-v5-vs-end-v6-lead-to-different-result-w-forked-5yvtj?file=/src/App.js I'm not sure off-hand without further testing if *actual* nested `Route` components would behave differently.

Comment: Many thanks! I was getting home page as active even if I was on another page eg: about page, the "end" prop was the key solution!